# How to do Parameters in views_export_data

Tags: drupal, export, view

I have a little problem. I want to export XML format so I did use views export data module in drupal7. It is a good module but I want to do parameters in XML path like that http://www.example.com/xml/articles?page=1
and http://api.androidhive.info/list_paging/?page=1. This URL accepts “page” (page number – 1, 2, 3 ..) parameter as a GET variable. How to do that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a **pager**. If the pager doesn't work use [Services Views](https://drupal.org/project/services_views) module for the xml export.